# Fetching class from array of circles created using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

```
var a1 = lineGroup.selectAll("circle")[0]; // gives array of circles
//Here is my code which is not working:
var a1 = lineGroup.selectAll("circle")[0]; 
function classArray() {
   return lineGroup.select("circle").attr("class");
}
var a = a1.map(classArray);
```

Following is the array of circles i get:

```
[<circle cx=​"74" cy=​"425.5" r=​"8" class=​"limited circleSmall preliteracy">​</circle>​, <circle cx=​"108" cy=​"368" r=​"8" class=​"intermediate circleSmall earlywriting">​</circle>​, <circle cx=​"142" cy=​"273.7" r=​"8" class=​"advanced circleSmall preliteracy">​</circle>​, <circle cx=​"346" cy=​"391" r=​"8" class=​"basic circleSmall writing">​</circle>​, <circle cx=​"380" cy=​"460" r=​"8" class=​"limited circleSmall preliteracy">​</circle>​, <circle cx=​"380" cy=​"172.5" r=​"8" class=​"basic circleSmall reading">​</circle>​, <circle cx=​"414" cy=​"151.79999999999998" r=​"8" class=​"basic circleSmall reading">​</circle>​, <circle cx=​"448" cy=​"105.8" r=​"8" class=​"intermediate circleSmall reading">​</circle>​, <circle cx=​"482" cy=​"96.59999999999998" r=​"8" class=​"intermediate circleSmall reading">​</circle>​, <circle cx=​"516" cy=​"80.50000000000001" r=​"8" class=​"high circleSmall reading">​</circle>​]
```

My doubt is, how will I check if my class name is preliteracy, reading, high, intermediate, writing, earlywriting (i.e.last value of classes)? 
How could I get class name in different array?

Comment: I believe I explained how to use an `if` in my (unaccepted) answer for your last question, check it again. It's the same reasoning, but using `split(" ").pop()` to get the last class.

Comment: @Sally Once you seem to be new at SO, let me give you an advice: don't (just) say "thanks", accept the working answer. Doing that, people will be more inclined to help you next time you ask. Otherwise, people will simply mentally blacklist you...